# Pandas dataframe grouping by two columns, count and sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df, which I would like to group by 'Name' so there is an 'A' and 'B' count column and a 'total sales' sum column:

eg turn this:

```
data = {'A or B' : ['A','A','B','B','A','B'],
        'Name' : ['Ben','Ben','Ben','Sam','Sam','Sam'],
        'Sales ($)' : [10,5,2,5,6,7]
       }

df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['A or B','Name','Sales ($)'])
```

so it looks like this:

```
grouped_data = {'A' : [2,1],
        'B' : [1,2],
        'Name' : ['Ben','Sam'],
        'Total Sales ($)' : [17,18]
       }

df=pd.DataFrame(grouped_data, columns = ['A','B','Name','Total Sales ($)'])
```

Comment: This is groupby with agg , check the official document ~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with `pd.get_dummies`, `join` and `groupby`+`sum`:

```
pd.get_dummies(df['A or B'])\
  .join(df.drop('A or B',1))\
  .groupby('Name',as_index=False).sum()
```

Output:

```
  Name  A  B  Sales ($)
0  Ben  2  1         17
1  Sam  1  2         18
```

---

**Details:**

First, use `get_dummies` to get categorical variable into dummy/indicator variables:

```
pd.get_dummies(df['A or B'])
#   A  B
#0  1  0
#1  1  0
#2  0  1
#3  0  1
#4  1  0
#5  0  1
```

Then use join, to concat the dummies with original df with `'A or B'` column dropped:

```
pd.get_dummies(df['A or B']).join(df.drop('A or B',1))
#   A  B Name  Sales ($)
#0  1  0  Ben         10
#1  1  0  Ben          5
#2  0  1  Ben          2
#3  0  1  Sam          5
#4  1  0  Sam          6
#5  0  1  Sam          7
```

And finally, do the `groupby`+`sum` based on name:

```
pd.get_dummies(df['A or B']).join(df.drop('A or B',1)).groupby('Name',as_index=False).sum()
#  Name  A  B  Sales ($)
#0  Ben  2  1         17
#1  Sam  1  2         18
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work with aggregations inside `groupby`

```
df.groupby(['Name']).agg(A = ('A or B', lambda x: (x=='A').sum())
                        ,B = ('A or B', lambda x: (x=='B').sum())
                        ,total = ('Sales ($)', 'sum')).reset_index()
#output
    Name    A   B   total
0   Ben     2   1   17
1   Sam     1   2   18
```

Answer (score 0):

Step by step solution:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'A or B' : ['A','A','B','B','A','B'],
        'Name' : ['Ben','Ben','Ben','Sam','Sam','Sam'],
        'Sales ($)' : [10,5,2,5,6,7]
       }

df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['A or B','Name','Sales ($)'])

#first create dummy for 'A or B' column
y = pd.get_dummies(df['A or B'])

#concatenate with original data frame
df=pd.concat([y,df], axis=1)
#delete the column
del df['A or B']

#now do the group by
df=df.groupby('Name').agg({'A':'sum',
                         'B':'sum', 
                         'Sales ($)': 'sum'})

#reset the index
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Name  A  B  Sales ($)
0  Ben  2  1         17
1  Sam  1  2         18
```